# Google Sheets: Formula to check column, match cell, return adjacent cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with a schedule of deliveries output to individual days and would like to include a new set of data on these days from a sheet titled **Catering**.

I have a condition that works, but I'm not able to figure out how to make it a broader formula.

```
=IF(B1=Catering!A1, Catering!B1, "No known catering")
```

This checks a date in B1 on current sheet against a date on the Catering sheet in A1 and returns the value of B1.

What I would like it to do is match current sheet B1 against Catering A:A and if there is a match, return the adjacent cell value ie. if current sheet B1 matches Catering A5 from Catering A:A, return Catering B5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `VLOOKUP` like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1:B, Catering!A1:B, 2, 0), "No known catering"))
```

or for date and match:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1:B, Catering!A1:B, {1,2}, 0), "No known catering"))
```

or if you don't need array:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1, Catering!A1:B, 2, 0), "No known catering")
```

Comment: I get the following error: Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in F17.

Comment: The third one gets no error, but returns no known catering when there is one.

Comment: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1, Catering!A1:B, 2, 0), "No known catering")

That did it - I'll check it with other days now.

Comment: Works beautifully ! Thanks so much :)

Comment: This is slightly off topic, but how would I include an importrange function in this formula if I wanted to break out the Catering sheet?

Comment: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1, IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Catering!A1:B"), 2, 0), "No known catering")` but you need to run importrange first as standalone and click on that button "allow access" which will popup un that #REF! error

Comment: Perfect. Thanks again.