# Google Sheets: Joining multiple cell values from source

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to get a formula that pulls a value from a sheet based on a date to find all occurrences and join them together.

My original question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54829626/google-sheets-formula-to-check-column-match-cell-return-adjacent-cell/) for context.

This works really well, but if a user submits a new order at a later date for a date that already has a submission, I get the first and not any additional.

Here's my current code, which also checks for comma and space, and adds a carriage return.

```
=regexreplace(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1, IMPORTRANGE("source", "B2:C"), 2, 0)), ", ", char(10))
```

How can I combine multiple cell values based on criteria?

Comment: Here's the sheet reflecting the submissions - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_d-PXWWmXP4CDhzwm0NfKTx8-i0oDQOz84R2SpakIyw/edit?usp=sharing

Here's the sheet with submissions https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JCOLm7ZQgR0qgtzq_98E4vDie7-FM-WlwiSZwgpB22k/edit?usp=sharing

Here's the submissions form https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScQSrYSpwCWsTAH4zf-PjId5kKpeOucTu1VMLEuWs5F_5hIng/viewform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,
 REGEXREPLACE(IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(
 "1JCOLm7ZQgR0qgtzq_98E4vDie7-FM-WlwiSZwgpB22k", "B2:C"),
 "select Col2 where Col1=date'"&TEXT(B1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")),
 ", ", CHAR(10))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Beautiful... Thank you!